# New column with ifelse loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
             TYC   Hi Mid Low Qty 
             1001  0  2    2   4
             1002  1  3    5   9
             1003  2  5    8   15
             1004  4  0    1   5
```

Its a data.frame named `TC_Sargento_Analysis`:

```
TC_Sargento_Analysis %>%
    group_by(TYC) %>% 
    summarise(Group = ifelse (Hi > .5*Qty) ,  "Buy any price" ,
    ifelse (Mid > .5*Qty) , "BUy mid price" , "Buy Low Price")
```

I am using this code for getting a new column named group which has "Buy any price" if Hi > 50% of Qty and "Buy mid" if Mid > 50% of Qty and same for Low.

but it gives me this error :

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: argument
>   "no" is missing, with no default.

I have also created a function for the conditions using ifelse

```
Class_Analysis <- function(a , b , c , d){
n <- length(a)
z <- character()

for(i in seq_along(a)[-c(1, n)]){
    ifelse(a[i] > .5*d[i])  
        z[i] <- "Hi"
} 

for(i in seq_along(b)[-c(1, n)]){
ifelse(b[i] > .5*d[i])  
Z[i] <- "Mid" 
Z[i] <- 'Low'
}
Z
}
```

When i us this code with the function

```
Class_Analysis(TC_Sargento_Analysis$Hi , 
TC_Sargento_Analysis$Mid ,TC_Sargento_Analysis$Low
TC_Sargento_Analysis$Qty)
```

It gives me this error:

> Error in ifelse(a[i] > 0.5 * d[i]) :    argument "no" is missing, with
>   no default

What am i doing wrong? Thanks i am new to r trying to learn doing analysis.

Comment: Your syntax for `ifelse` is wrong. May be you meant `ifelse(b[i] > .5*d[i],  
 "Mid",   'Low')`

Comment: There's an error in your ifelse syntax. Try `TC_Sargento_Analysis %>%
group_by(TYC) %>% 
summarise(Group = ifelse (Hi > .5*Qty,  "Buy any price" ,
ifelse (Mid > .5*Qty , "Buy mid price" , "Buy Low Price")))`

Comment: Thanks you guys its working i guess i was not using the brackets correctly.